# my websites search results are immune to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, search

I have a website where I can search for things in the database, let it be boats for now.

I use this form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchField" name="searchField" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

And this jquery to display serch results

```
//Autocomplete search field
$("#searchField").keyup(function(){
    var input = $("#searchField").val();
    $("#searchResults").html("");
    input = $.trim(input);
    if(input){
        $.post( "source/pages/processing/search_boats.php", {inputString:""+input+""}, function( data ) {
            $( "#searchResults" ).html( data );
        });
    }   
});
```

the search_boats.php look like this:

```
<?php 
$input = $_POST['inputString'];
$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT boat_name FROM boats WHERE boat_name LIKE '%".$input."%' ORDER BY boat_name LIMIT 5 ");
echo "<ul id='searchUL'>";
while($row = $sql -> fetch_array()){
?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#" onclick="return displayRest();"><? echo $row['boat_name']?></a>
        </div>
    </div>      
<?
```

For now this working perfectly - just like I want it. However, when these search results appear on the website I can not add any click events on them. Ive tried making buttons, anchors. I suspect jquery is not ready for this added piece of search results that Im displaing the user. For example, I'm able to hide a div called myDiv on click on any anchor tags

like so..

```
$("a").click(function(){
        $("#myDiv").toggle();
    });
```

but when I click anchors on the search results, the myDiv isn't being hidden.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - like `$('#searchResults').on('click', 'a', function(){$("#myDiv").toggle();})`

Comment: try `$(document).on("click", "a", function() {`

Comment: Another piece of PHP code vulnerable to SQL injection...

Comment: dont mind the vulnerability for now... but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(){
      $("#myDiv").toggle();
});
```